# "Node ."と打ち込むと"Cannot find module"とエラーが表示される

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

現在Node.jsとDiscord.jsを使いBOTを作ってるのですが、コードを全部書いた後に
「Node .」とターミナルに打ち込むと以下のようなエラーが起きます。
色々なサイトで調べてみたのですが中々解決策が見つかりません。
もし宜しければお手数をおかけしますが回答を貰えると嬉しいです。
エラーは以下の文です。

```
node .
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:615
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\JohmaruBOT.1.0.0'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

追記　
global.module.pathsと打った結果

```
'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\repl\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Program Files\\node_modules',
  'C:\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\johma\\.node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\johma\\.node_libraries',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\lib\\node' ]
```

と表記されました。

Comment: nodeコンソールで `global.module.paths`  と入力した結果を追記して頂けますか？

Comment: global.module.paths
[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\repl\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Program Files\\node_modules',
  'C:\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\johma\\.node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\johma\\.node_libraries',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\lib\\node' ]
と表記されました。

Comment: カレントディレクトリに index.js は置かれていますか？

Comment: 返答が遅くなって大変申し訳ございません。

Comment: 当方色々試行錯誤してみたのですがnode play.jsと打つと
起動できたのでindex.jsが原因みたいでした。
知識不足で大変申し訳無いです。